# Should I be using an OUTER APPLY to associate an Id number to a persons name?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working with 2 tables. These are ancient tables that I do NOT have the ability to edit myself. I have to work with the structure given to me in this case.

One has a "CaseID" and the Event code, like this:

Table 1 :

```
| CaseID | Event |   Date   |
|:------:|:-----:|:--------:|
|  BL221 |  FTA  | 02/01/19 |
|  BL331 |  FTA  | 03/01/19 |
|  BL444 |  FTA  | 05/01/19 |
|  BL444 |  FTA  | 05/01/19 |
|  BL881 |  FTA  | 12/01/19 |
|  BL991 |  BEW  | 05/01/19 |
|  BL995 |  BEW  | 12/01/19 |
```

A single CaseID can have many different events, including duplicates (2 "FTA" events on BL444). In this case I am interested in the 'FTA''s

My other table associates those CaseID's with an individual, with their name and a UserID, like this:

Table 2:

```
| FirstName | LastName | UsrID | CaseID |
|:---------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|
|  Jessica  |   Smith  |  885  |  BL111 |
|  Jessica  |   Smith  |  885  |  BL221 |
|  Jessica  |   Smith  |  885  |  BL331 |
|  Jessica  |   Smith  |  885  |  BL444 |
|  Jessica  |  Stanley |  885  |  BL881 |
```

As you can see, Jessica was recently married. Her UsrID will stay the same (885) but I need to be able to associate her new name to that ID within a query.

We are using the CaseID to determine which direction we are moving through time as they are sequential.

As mentioned, I am simply trying to count individual's instances of the FTA event, figure out how many per CaseID, and stick their (most current) name on the end of it. With the example data I'd like to see:

```
|       Name       | UsrID | Hits | NumofCases |
|:----------------:|:-----:|:----:|:----------:|
| Stanley, Jessica |  885  |   5  |      4     |
|     Doe, John    |  225  |   2  |      1     |
```

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT TB.NAME_LAST + ', ' + TB.NAME_FIRST as Name,  TB.UsrID, COUNT(TB.UsrID) as Hits, COUNT(DISTINCT(TA.CaseID)) as NumofCases
FROM Table1 as TA
JOIN Table2 as TB on TA.CaseID = TB.CaseID
where TA.DT_COURT_EVENT between '20190201' and '20200101' and TA.Event = 'FTA'
group by TB.NAME_LAST + ', ' + TB.NAME_FIRST, TB.UsrID
order by Hits desc
```

This is fairly close, but that nasty GROUP BY is causing me to separate all instances once Jessica's name was changed:

```
|       Name       | UsrID | Hits | NumofCases |
|:----------------:|:-----:|:----:|:----------:|
|  Smith, Jessica  |  885  |   4  |      3     |
|     Doe, John    |  225  |   2  |      1     |
| Stanley, Jessica |  885  |   1  |      1     |
```

So I tried this:

```
SELECT TB.UsrID, COUNT(TB.UsrID) as Hits, COUNT(DISTINCT(TA.CaseID)) as NumofCases, C.Name
from Table1 TA
JOIN Table2 as TB on TA.CaseID = TB.CaseID
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 (C.NAME_LAST + ',' + C.NAME_First) as Name
                    FROM   Table2 C
                    WHERE  TA.CaseID = C.CaseID
                    ORDER  BY TA.Date desc) C
where TA.Date between '20190901' and '20200101' and TA.Event = 'FTA'
group by TB.UsrID, C.Name
order by Hits desc
```

Because I figured that "Select TOP 1" would be what I was after, but I get the same results as before.

I want to avoid the XY problem here, so I apologize for the long-windedness and funky title. Just want to show all of my cards in case I am going about this in an inefficient way

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know the most recent name?  There is no ordering column in the second table.

Comment: It doesn't look you need an outer apply here. How do you find "...their most current name..."? As Gordon mention there's no column that tells you the date or something similar.

Comment: Seems like you shouldn't be storing the name of the person *and* their User ID in `Table2`; the user's name (and other details) should be in a User Details table, that always has the user's *current* name. It's not that you "need" `OUTER APPLY`, it's that the design needs fixing. If you need the store historical data (like old names) then create history table or use a temporal table.

Comment: @Larnu I've edited my post. I should've mentioned that the structure of the tables are not up to me, but I certainly cannot edit them as much as I agree with you.

Comment: Just because something is old, doesn't mean it can't be changed. And just because you're unsure how to fix the design, doesn't mean we can't show you how to.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Right, I am currently using the CaseID's instance as a reference to the point in time. 

Since CaseID BL881 happened on 12/01/19 this was the most recent time we saw UsrID 885, and that was the first time her last name was "Stanley"

Comment: Try using row_number() as a separate join to table1 and table2, joined together to get the most recent date

Comment: @Larnu this is a table with millions of rows dating back to the late 80's. Thousands of people are using this table across dozens of agencies. Trust me, I cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` like you originally intended, but you need to join on `UsrID` and fix your sort order.

```
SELECT ca.Name, t2.UsrID, COUNT(*) AS Hits, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.CaseID) AS NumofCases
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.CaseID = t1.CaseID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 LastName + ', ' + FirstName as Name
             FROM Table2
             WHERE UsrID = t2.UsrID
             ORDER BY CaseID DESC) ca
WHERE t1.Event = 'FTA'
GROUP BY ca.Name, t2.UsrID
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thanks Derrick.

Answer (score 0):

I see.  This is a weird setup.  You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select userid, count(*), count(distinct caseid),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end)
from (select t1.*, t2.last_name + ' ' + t2.first_name as name
             row_number() over (partition by t2.usrid order by t1.date desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1 join 
           table2 t2
           on t1.caseid = t2.caseid
      where t1.event = 'FA'
     ) t12
group by userid;
```